# Theoretically, how does one take the keyboard and touchpad drivers from Ubuntu on ChromeOS and convert them for use with Windows?

Tags: windows-7, linux, drivers, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I asked this on AskUbuntu, but they said it was 'off-topic' and to post it on a list of other forums (including this one), so:

In theory, it is possible to install Windows on a Chromebook. To do so, one either needs usb peripherals or the proprietary drivers to use the keyboard and touchpad. Unfortunately, Google has not released them to the public and probably won't in the foreseeable future. So, in place of that, I want to take the drivers that allow them to function in linux (Ubuntu) and use them with windows. Yes, I know Windows and Linux are two COMPLETELY different kernels, but I've found sources stating that it is possible to load the kernels. I ask that if anyone knows anything about this, please help me make this happen. It's been done on a few 'beefy' Chromebooks in the past, but never in a method that would allow ALL Chromebooks to load the operating system.

Sources:

Digital Trends: http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-install-windows-chromebook/

El Pauper: http://www.elpauer.org/2011/03/linux-drivers-running-on-windows/

Keep in mind, I want to expand compatibility, not be limited to what's already been done.

Comment: Yeah, good luck with this! If you don't even have a theoretical idea of how to accomplish this I believe you'll need it.

Comment: @notjustme I've got a _theroetical_ idea of how to do this, but lack the resources to do it at the moment. Thanks for your encouragement, it's helpful to see others show interest in something I've said. Hopefully, in the next few weeks, I'll have a full answer to the question, whether I figure it out with a few developer friends or figure it out myself.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have been confused by the title starting with "Theoretically, how does one". Good luck still though!

Comment: The thing is, you can definitely install Windows on a Chromebook, with tweaking, but I've read that the keyboard and touchpad use drivers that aren't compatible with windows, which means you'd need USB peripherals to operate the device. The problem with that is, there are only two USB ports on most Chromebooks. I want it to work as-is, without a USB keyboard and mouse. I'm planning to try it soon, but for now, it's all in theory.

Comment: **Note from the future:** on a low-powered Chromebook, it is impossible to run Windows 8/10. Have not tried lower versions, but it appears there's an issue getting a windows kernel to boot at all. Will investigate eventually.